# How to devise an algorithm that suggests feasible cooking recipes?

Tags: machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, modelling, recommendation-systems

I once had a veteran in my course that created an algorithm that would suggest cooking recipes. At first, all sort of crazy recipes would come out. Then, she would train the cooking algorithm with real recipes and eventually it would suggest very good ones.

I believe she used something related to Bayes Theorem or Clustering, but she is long gone and so is the algorithm. I have searched the internet but looking for cooking recipes will yield any sort of results but not the one I am looking for. So, my question is:

> What techniques can be used to devise an algorithm that (randomly) suggests feasible recipes (without using a database of fixed recipes)?

Why would I bother looking for a cooking algorithm? Well, it was a very good example of a real world application of the underlying concepts, and such algorithm could be useful in different settings that are closer to the real world.

Comment: It might be worth looking at various types of [evolutionary algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evolutionary_algorithm)

Comment: ... or for light relief, [this from xkcd](http://xkcd.com/720/)

Comment: @Henry: And which function would you use for fitness? That is the main point of the question!

Comment: Can the person who voted to close explain the reason behind his vote? Voting to close without giving a reason does not help the OP improve his question.

Comment: @Raphael Mouse from The Matrix:"How did the machines know what Tasty Wheat tasted like. huh? Maybe they got it wrong. Maybe what I think Tasty Wheat tasted like actually tasted like oatmeal or tuna fish. That makes you wonder about a lot of things. You take chicken for example, maybe they couldn't figure out what to make chicken taste like, which is why chicken tastes like everything."

Comment: The comments seems more exotic than the question itself.

Comment: @AlextenBrink, I did vote to close as not a real question. I don't think it is answerable in its current form ("I forgot what I see yesterday in the newspaper, it was either in Guardian or Independent, can someone tell me what it was?") and I didn't and don't see how the question can be improved (therefore didn't leave any comment).

Comment: I can change the question to ask on how to do this with Bayes Theorem if you prefer, thats what she used, so it is answerable. I just asked if there was a better approach than that instead. Does this suffice?

Comment: Can you elaborate on the problem setup a bit. What exactly are your inputs? recipes? ingredients? What exactly do you expect as an output?

Comment: @Kaveh: I think you put too much value on the anecdote. I edited to clarify the core question which is, imho a very valid applied question that asks for CS (more specifically machine learning) expertise.

Comment: @Nick input for training are a set of recipes. thats it. The output of the program is a suggested recipe. If you ask a recipe without training crazy recipe output. After training, great recipe output.

Comment: I still think it needs further improvement: is an algorithm that just randomly outputs some recipe an acceptable answer? (but I am not an expert in machine-learning and I don't have suggestions for how to improve it).

Comment: Precisely define a "feasible" recipe. What distinguishes it from an infeasible or less feasible one? You need to suggest a criterion that lends itself to quantification.

Comment: Emre, feasability here is manual. She showed us the recipe. How does it look infeasible is a matter of reasoning: You see salt on a sweet recipe, or a very weird combination that not even cultural difference can make that acceptable. Feasible recipes on the other hand were actually recipes that resembled other recipes that are common known, an example we had was a Cake! Sometimes it had some `huh!?` ingredient, but it wasnt as bad as putting salt in the cake! (a chocolate cake, mind you!). Hope it is clear now! :)

Comment: You can use [salt on a dessert to heighten contrast](http://www.nytimes.com/2000/08/30/dining/there-s-new-flavor-town-it-s-salt-dessert-traditions-go-over-shoulder.html). If a feasible recipe is merely a minor variation on a known one then the solution is simple: maintain a list of acceptable alternatives for each ingredient (e.g., one vegetable for another) then return all the combinations.

Comment: Just to make sure I clarified it properly, the point on the question is not about how to verify its feasibility. Just one that does that and you can visually see it is feasible. (I don't want an algorithm that toss crazy stuff after trained).

Comment: You still have not given a proper feasibility criterion.

Comment: Emre, sorry. I will try to be more formal on this since its still confusing soon (have to run). If it still not clean after that we can maybe discuss on chat so I can better understand where is the confusion and edit here for the community.

Comment: @Emre: The point of machine learning techniques *is* that you do not have to define the quality measure beforehand, because you can not. Essentially, the measure depends on your training data.

Comment: @Emre, are you looking for a formula to verify a percentual out of it? I am not concerned with that, as I said it is supposed to be reasonable. My imagination of undergraduate can't even imagine how an algorithm would know what are good recipes and bad recipes since there are all sort of crazy stuff out there that it is eatable and not. The point of the question is not how to know if it is good or not, it is just to find an algorithm that is intended for this and do it properly. I am getting confused. Maybe you are focusing too much on the 'feasibility' word?

Comment: Can you give a few example inputs and outputs you want to generate? I just can't see what makes a recipe admissible (feasible). For example you suggested that salt should not go in desserts, but I disagreed. How is the algorithm to decide?

Comment: Maybe you can narrow down to a specific culture recipes, or a specific domain then. Say, desserts. Then, well, heres another example, there is a dessert with duck and chicken. Does that still looks feasible to you? Something just won't fit right no matter whats your view point.

Comment: Don't be so sure; [chicken pudding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tavuk_g%C3%B6%C4%9Fs%C3%BC) is a staple Turkish dessert. And it tastes very good too. I think I'll sit this question out because it seems ill-posed to me.

Comment: Emre, read my comment again. I said to use culture as a bound. Your last comment don't make sense for me given that constraint.Since no one seems to suggest a better approach (aside the 2 up voted answer) I guess I will take some time trying to find an answer for it as well even more than what I did the previous months. The comments here are big enough already. If you have a suggestion of improvement please edit the question and ask for peer review highlighting it as long as you don't change the question itself, but please don't close it otherwise I won't be able to answer or edit it anymore.

Answer (score 4):

Hmm, using Bayes Theorem to make new recipes out of old recipes. I imagine you first would want the algorithm to pull apart the ingredients into a form it understands (not sure if we are using NLP for that, or if you manually enter the data in yourself, that's neither here nor there.) From there...

I envision something like this.

Test Data analyzed. Now we have a list of recipes and the probabilities that each ingredient will take place alongside another ingredient, and in what quantities. After we have this data then you would have the program randomly make the new recipes. First it cycles through a list of all the known ingredients, then randomly selects a main ingredient, from there it uses the probabilities of an ingredient given another ingredient to start throwing in more random ingredients, all the while matching appropriate trained data for quantities and compatible ingredients.

Might I suggest that when creating a new recipe the program be given information like, I want something sweet, or something sour, or for instance something mostly made up of wheat.

Hopefully this helps a bit.

Answer (score 3):

For a broad US-centric dataset of nearly 2000 recipes you could look at the [Armed Forces Recipe Service](http://www.quartermaster.army.mil/jccoe/publications/food_links.html). This does not answer your question, but would provide you with real-world training data.

The requirements for the problem are probably difficult to articulate for most people and the selected approach will likely end up implicitly adjusting fitness in the way you have suggested. Foods in geenral are very culture-specific and the approach would probably travel very poorly without extensive tuning.

This also needs substantial sematic, and domain, knowledge to prepare more than just a list of ingredients. After all, coffee-flavoured ice-cream with wafer, cafe au lait and a croissant and tira misu would otherwise be indistinguishable.

Comment: "This does not answer your question" -- exactly, so it should be a comment. I see you are not allowed to comment yet; I flagged for conversion.

Comment: @Raphael: not converting this, because it's too long and - although it may not be an ideal answer - as a whole it does attempt to address the problem. If you feel it is unhelpful, please down-vote it. Pekka, although this may not be the most productive source of new culinary art, it is an interesting - and relatable - problem... If you could expand your answer to discuss the specifics of developing such an algorithm, it might be more acceptable.

Answer (score 3):

Recipe generation is commonly used as an example application for Case Based Reasoning systems. It is even used as an example on the [Wikipedia Page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Case-based_reasoning). A google search for "case based reasoning recipes" yields numerous results.

Answer (score 1):

The class of algorithms you are looking for is the bandits one. They are usually used to handle the exploration part of a classification problem.

A basic approach would be to represent the recipes as a limited bag of components (a vector of booleans with at most k non 0 values) and to use LinUCB to select a set of components. Then the feedback would be 'like' or 'dont like'. Of course if you are a bayesian you could prefer to use Trueskill (using the Adpredictor variant).

Something less basic would require to use a kernel instead of a linear separation. Kernel ucb can help to handle that part. But at some point I think it would become usefull to pay attention to the chemical compositions of the aliments because at the end you probably want to achieve a balance between different basic tastes.